# R dcast and dates

Tags: r, date, format, dcast

I have a simple data frame

```
    SubjectID ImgTP   ScanDate
1      01-001    B0 2019-06-28
2      01-001    PO 2019-06-30
3      01-001   W02 2019-07-09
4      01-001   W06 2019-08-15
5      01-001   W12 2019-09-13
6      01-001   W24 2019-12-13
7      01-001 INT01 2019-07-25
8      01-001 INT02 2019-10-25
9      01-002    B0 2019-07-25
10     01-002    PO 2019-07-26
11     01-002   W02 2019-08-15
12     01-002   W06 2019-09-05
13     01-002   W12 2019-10-24
14     01-002   W24 2020-01-23
```

I want to create a table the has `SubjectID` vs `TP` and displays date in the cell.

```
basic_table <- dcast(myDataArm,  SubjectID ~ ImgTP, value.var = "ScanDate",
                      fun.aggregate = function(x) lubridate::as_date(x), fill = 0)
```

However the dates in the table are reported as numbers. Why is it not displaying correctly?

Comment: i'm assuming you are using the `reshape2` package, it seems like a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289731/posixct-values-become-numeric-in-reshape2-dcast). I don't think this package is in development anymore, and so you might try whatever flavor of the month hadley uses in the `tidyverse`. interestingly, if you convert to a `data.table`: `x <- data.table::as.data.table(myDataArm)`, then use `data.table::dcast(x, ...)`, you will get the right result. then you can `as.data.frame()` back if you want

Comment: @rawr ... flavor of the month. lol  You're too kind. :D :D

Comment: thanks, I understand the mistake now.  It does not work as I needed, works best with reshape

Answer (score 1):

You could just use reshape in base R.  It creates names of the form `ScanDate.B0` so we remove everything prior to and including the dot in the second line to get nicer names.

```
r <- reshape(myDataArm, dir = "wide", idvar = "SubjectID", timevar = "ImgTP")
names(r) <- sub(".*\\.", "", names(r))
r
##   SubjectID         B0         PO        W02        W06        W12        W24      INT01      INT02
## 1    01-001 2019-06-28 2019-06-30 2019-07-09 2019-08-15 2019-09-13 2019-12-13 2019-07-25 2019-10-25
## 9    01-002 2019-07-25 2019-07-26 2019-08-15 2019-09-05 2019-10-24 2020-01-23       <NA>       <NA>
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "    SubjectID ImgTP   ScanDate
1      01-001    B0 2019-06-28
2      01-001    PO 2019-06-30
3      01-001   W02 2019-07-09
4      01-001   W06 2019-08-15
5      01-001   W12 2019-09-13
6      01-001   W24 2019-12-13
7      01-001 INT01 2019-07-25
8      01-001 INT02 2019-10-25
9      01-002    B0 2019-07-25
10     01-002    PO 2019-07-26
11     01-002   W02 2019-08-15
12     01-002   W06 2019-09-05
13     01-002   W12 2019-10-24
14     01-002   W24 2020-01-23"
myDataArm <- read.table(text = Lines)
myDataArm$ScanDate <- as.Date(myDataArm$ScanDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pivot_wider` function from tidyr is one option.

```
library(tidyr)

  pivot_wider(myDataArm, names_from=ImgTP, values_from=ScanDate)

# A tibble: 2 x 9
  SubjectID B0         PO         W02        W06        W12        W24        INT01      INT02     
  <chr>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
1 01-001    2019-06-28 2019-06-30 2019-07-09 2019-08-15 2019-09-13 2019-12-13 2019-07-25 2019-10-25
2 01-002    2019-07-25 2019-07-26 2019-08-15 2019-09-05 2019-10-24 2020-01-23 NA         NA
```

You could also use the `reshape` function, but "ScanDate" appears in the wide variable names.

```
reshape(myDataArm, direction="wide", idvar = "SubjectID", 
                   v.names="ScanDate", timevar="ImgTP")


  SubjectID ScanDate.B0 ScanDate.PO ScanDate.W02 ScanDate.W06 ScanDate.W12 ScanDate.W24 ...
1    01-001  2019-06-28  2019-06-30   2019-07-09   2019-08-15   2019-09-13   2019-12-13
9    01-002  2019-07-25  2019-07-26   2019-08-15   2019-09-05   2019-10-24   2020-01-23
```

Comment: not to be confused with `tidyr::spread(myDataArm, ImgTP, ScanDate)` !!